# AS3: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, removechild, displayobject

I can't figure this one out, i'm sorry - really an ActionScript noobie here. I've searched for the problem but the answers i keep finding don't solve my problems. Anyone know whats wrong?

```
public function KikkerOgen() 
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, isClicked);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, Knipperen);
            timer.start();
            gotoAndStop(13);
        }

        function isClicked (event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            removeChild(this);
        }
```

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2025: Het opgegeven DisplayObject moet een onderliggend item van de aanroeper zijn.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at KikkerOgen/isClicked()[/Users/Amanda/Documents/Hanze/Jaar 1/Periode 4/MTM3/Spel/KikkerOgen.as:34]
Cannot display source code at this location. -- This is my error and the code it refers too is in my main post.

Comment: It was my fault, sorry, i didn't see it, look at the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry your problem is in:

```
removeChild(this);
```

You are trying to remove the object from the object itself!!!

That's what you should do:

```
this.parent.removeChild(this);
```